# African American?

Tags: meaning

Almost every country in America have black people even though, the United States of America considers that African American are black people born in that country, Why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [History of "Asian American" / "African American" nomenclature](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19191/history-of-asian-american-african-american-nomenclature)

Comment: I think that Bladorthin's comment would be a lot more suitable with any sort of evidence backing it up - although, in fairness, I'm not sure legitimate such evidence exists. This Wikipedia passage recounts the history of the term, and it's essentially the opposite of what Bladorthin describes. In the future, please try to include research, evidence, and independent verification to your assertions on this site.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Americans#Terminology

Comment: @Non-Contradiction What a diplomatic way to say completely, totally, and howlingly wrong. I should take lessons from you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the kernel of this question is about the use of "America."

Even though "North America" and "South America" name continents, "The Americas" refers to them both, and "The States" is how the US is often referred to in, say, Europe, most citizens of the US refer to their own country as "America." Since the term was developed in the US by US citizens, they thought of "American" as a suitable second half for the term, as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Americans#Terminology