# Is describing an object as "oriental" offensive?

Tags: grammar

For example, an Oriental cream or Oriental paste. Would this be offensive?

Comment: related: 1. [Why did the descriptive “Orientals” shift into a pejorative?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18814/why-did-the-descriptive-orientals-shift-into-a-pejorative) 2. [Proper term for people from eastern Asia](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51783/proper-term-for-people-from-eastern-asia)

Comment: Any word at all can be offensive. You cucumber paste.

Comment: @RegDwigнt How dare you!

Answer (score 2):

Saying something is oriental is fine when you're talking about objects such as cream and paste. The offence comes when you're speaking about people, where one would say Asian instead.